# Change of Variable (conformal map)

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is an analytic function defined on the unit disk, $D$.   I want to evaluate

$\int_{D} f(\omega) dA(\omega)$

using a change of variable.   Suppose $\phi$ is a conformal map of the $D$ onto itself.

Does

$\int_{D} f(\omega) dA(\omega) = \int_{D} f(\phi(z)) |\phi^{'}(z)|^{2}  dA(z) $?,

where $\phi^{'}$ is the derivative of $\phi$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because $|\phi'(z)|^2$ is the determinant of the Jacobian of $\phi$, this follows from the substitution formula for open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$, as seen for example in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables), which contains further references for the more general result.  Technically, to apply the result directly you would break up each side into real and imaginary parts.